# Clock icon on a single WhatsApp chat message on both side

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Today, I was talking with one of my friends on WhatsApp and suddenly a clock icon showed on some messages.

First, I assumed that there might be an internet issue, so I sent messages to other contacts on WhatsApp and they were delivered. But for half an hour, my friend's chat was still showing a clock sign, and the same issue was faced by my friend.

I faced this issue for the first time in my life. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the app in the background and open the app, by the time it processes the messages might have been sent from your side;

Otherwise, turn on and off flight mode.

Sometimes if there is a sufficient amount of reception and it is not sending or receiving any texts, then it is better to take some time to reset back to default mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out from all **'Linked Devices'**. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, although I've never faced such problems on Telegram.
This solves my problem:

1. Find Whatsapp here phone setting > application manager and Force Stop it.
2. From there tap the the storage button and clear cache (Not clear data!)
3. Start the app again